# Why URLSession doesn't go in URLSessionDownloadDelegate?

Tags: swift, delegates, urlsession

i try to print progress of downloading using URLSessionDownloadDelegate, but delegate's methods don't work
Although image is download, progress don't print

I have button

```
@IBAction func downloadTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let image = "https://neilpatel-qvjnwj7eutn3.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/applelogo.jpg"
        guard let url = URL(string: image) else {return}

        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
        session.downloadTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let url = data else {return}
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

            } catch {

            }


        }.resume()

    }
```

And extension

```
extension DownloadingViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("=====FINISH=====")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        let progress = Float(bytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesWritten)
        print(progress)
    }

}
```

nothing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

```
session.downloadTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
```

This means that the URLSession's `delegate` is ignored, because the download task has a completion handler which is used instead. So what you are seeing is the expected behavior.

---

If you wish to use a delegate, call

```
session.downloadTask(with: url)
```

and do *everything* in the delegate, including receiving the downloaded file.

---

On the other hand, if your goal is merely to display progress, there is no need for the delegate. The download task vends a `progress` object for this purpose. Example:

```
    let task = session.downloadTask(with:url) { fileURL, resp, err in
        // whatever
    }
    // self.prog is a UIProgressView
    self.prog.observedProgress = task.progress
    task.resume()
```